# SeriesChartType (enumeration) examples

Tags: asp.net, charts, sample

I'm using the ASP.NET charting library (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting) and the SeriesChartType enumeration has a ton of different chart types. I've done a fair amount of searching to try and find examples of what each chart type looks like but so far no luck.

Does anybody know if there is a list of the chart types with an example of each one somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the samples and run them locally:  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418